# Xamarin.Facebook vs Xamarin.Facebook.Android

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am looking at some source code for a Xamarin Android app where i have to update its Facebook sdk support. Looking at the installed packages i see that both `Xamarin.Facebook` and `Xamarin.Facebook.Adroid` are added to the same project;

[image]

Looking in Nuget.org i see that [Xamarin.facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.Android/) is some sort or prereleased or something unlike [Xamarin.Facebook.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.Android/) am i missing something here! are both of them needed to work with Facebook sdk in a Xamarin android app?

**EDIT**

Here are both installed nuget packages:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this an android app only or is it xamarin forms kindly always mention this

Comment: `Xamarin.Facebook` is dead, see __Last updated__ column of it

Comment: I think you just need to download Xamarin.Facebook.Android sdk, it can login with Facebook authentication, here are some article that you can take a look: [Xamarin.form](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-android-facebook-authentication-azure-app-service/), [Android](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-android-facebook-authentication-azure-app-service/)

Comment: you should use xamarin android and ios plugins with dependecy injection on xamarin.forms project. there are already nice articles explains how it easily can be done.

Comment: I am actually working on a Xamarin android project (not forms) any good articles on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would check the NuGet documents for [Xamarin.Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook/) plugin you will notice that they have not updated the stable NuGet package since `8/18/2015` i.e. fours years ago

And the last pre-release was released on `8/25/2015` which means basically it is being discontinued by Xamarin/Microsoft as is dead.

On the other hand [Xamarin.Facebook.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook.Android/) is still being maintained and if I am not wrong was just updated yesterday.

It would be wise if you just remove Xamarin.Facebook Nuget and take care of all the dependencies using the Android Nuget.